# TinyMCE disabled after reload of AJAX content

Tags: bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, tinymce, tinymce-5

we've integrated TinyMCE 5 in one of our projects and it is driving me up the wall.
Editable content for one of our items is loaded in a Bootstrap 4 modal dialog.
After the modal dialog is loaded tinyMCE is called for one of the textareas with:

```
tinyMCE.init( { selector: "textarea.tinymce",
                       theme: "silver",
                       width: "720",
                       menubar: false,
                       plugins: "spellchecker,image,paste,searchreplace,fullscreen,print,lists",
                       language: "de",
                       toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | numlist bullist | outdent indent | image | print"
                   } );
```

Before the modal window is closed TinyMCE is removed with the following code:

```
$('textarea.tinymce').each( function()
 {
  let mceItemID = $(this).attr('id');

     tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true, mceItemID);
     tinymce.remove('#' + mceItemID);
  });
```

We've tried with and without the execCommand, the result is always that when the modal window is opened for the second time the TinyMCE item is shown but does not have any content. It is also not clickable or focusable.
What else do we have to do to get TinyMCE to re-initialize properly?
Thanks

Comment: Why not just change the content of the TinyMCE for different items, instead of recreating and destroying it again and again? Or do you have different modals for different items each with a different textarea element?

Comment: Thanks Siddharth, I thought of that. The thing is that the content of the modal window is retrieved via AJAX from a django app. Just changing the content objects in the form would be a lot of effort. I have even thought of replace TinyMCE with something else - as it doesn't seem to work, but haven't found a good alternative yet.

Comment: When the data is loaded via ajax, you still are putting it into the textarea (and other fields) right? I'm just confused as to why is the recreation of the editor is needed, when it won't make a difference.

Comment: Hi Sidddharth, the user can edit different record details in a list. This opens a modal window with a form. The HTML for that form is generated by the python application on the server. After loading the HTML from the server we call a JavaScript function that tries to create a TinyMCE element out of one of the textareas - which works the first time, but does not for subsequent calls.

Comment: Ah, so the form is dynamic, got it. After you have re-init the textarea, do you get any error in the console?

Comment: Hi Siddharth unfortunately there are no error messages. If there were I would probably know better where to look for a solution.

Comment: Okay, I whipped up this https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/4cb58kav/, here an editor is initialized at load, then removed after 5 seconds (that should happen as your modal closes), and re-initialized after another 5 seconds (that should happen after your data is fetched again). Seems to work fine. Just compare the code.

Comment: Hi Siddharth, thank you very much for the effort.

Comment: I can't really see what you are doing different from what we tried. I'll have to break down our code and try to simplify it later. Have to go see the customer now and show a not really working prototype. :-) I'll keep you posted though. Regards Fredrick

Comment: Alright. I have a guess the `each` function on the editors might not be working properly because the form is dynamic, but can't be sure without debugging.

Comment: OK, I had checked whether the each function was working using an event procedure. I have found a solution though. I took your fiddle code and inserted it into the initialization procedure of the modal form. It worked. It even worked when opening the window multiple times - though after the first call the first init() call created a disabled textarea. After fiddling with the code I tried to just use a timeout call of 50 ms when calling the init function. That worked too, but TinyMCE was no longer automatically saving the content when the form was saved.

Comment: So, I used getContent() on the element and explicitly saved the TinyMCE content in the submit function of the form. Now it works - its a crutch but does the trick. Why these problems popped up I don't know. I am guessing it must have something to do with what bootstrap does after opening the modal window. Siddharth, thank you for taking the time to help!

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. Do post it as an answer and accept it, might help someone in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to call the init function asynchronously when creating the modal dialog:
in my initialization function for the modal dialog I now use:

```
setTimeount( function() { tinyMCE.init( selector: 'textarea#' + mceItemID,..);}, 50 );
```

Then, when closing the modal windows I call:

```
tinymce.remove( 'textarea#' + mceItemID );
```

Now I can call the dynamic modal window multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

To properly reinit the editor:

1. Save current content somewhere with [`getContent()`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#getcontent)
2. Instead of trying to remove TinyMCE items one by one, destroy the whole instance completely with [`destroy()`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#destroy)
3. Reinitialize
4. Use [`setContent()`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#setcontent) to add the content saved on step 1.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thanks. I just tried that, but seem to have problems with the correct use of the destroy function. I tried tinyMCE.destroy(false) and I get the error tinyMCE.destroy is not a function.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I read the documentation for TinyMCE, but I did not quit understand how to call the destroy function correctly. Can help me there?